# Magento 2 - Removing swatches.css from theme

Tags: magento2, css, xml, swatches

Its a pretty simple and straightforward question, at the moment my theme seems to be pulling through the following:

> Vendor/default/en_GB/Magento_Swatches/css/swatches.css

this isn't in my theme, and **Magento_Swatches** folder doesn't exist, its obviously pulling from the core.

But i don't want this, i've written my own styles for it and dont want it there. I tried in the following way:

> Vendor/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<remove src="Magento_Swatches/css/swatches.css" />
```

or

```
<remove src="css/swatches.css" />
```

Neither seems to work. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, i found the solution:

```
<remove src="Magento_Swatches::css/swatches.css"/>
```

I didn't realise the **::** was required. If anyone comes across this, hope it helps.

@Andy. Thank you for the solution it worked for me. This was helpful. The error was driving me crazy. Just want to add a suggestion. I am working on Magento 2.3.

Create a file in your theme folder, if it does not already exist. Do not modify Magento core files.

```
vi {mage_root_location}/app/design/frontend/Mgs/{your_theme_name}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

Inside that file find the  tag and add

```
<remove src="Magento_Swatches::css/swatches.css"/>
```

Should end up looking something like this

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        ...
        <remove src="Magento_Swatches::css/swatches.css"/>
        ...
    </head>
</page>
```

Source: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html